How to disable PlotRangeClipping in a plot for only one direction?
I have a plot whose curves leak out of the plot range if I set PlotRangeClipping -> False. But, I also need to enable it to display a unit above the frame.
A MWE is this:
tmp = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}];
padtmp = ImagePadding /. AbsoluteOptions[tmp, "ImagePadding"];
plot6 = Show[tmp, 
  Epilog -> 
   Text[Row@{"\[Times]", Superscript[10, -3]}, 
    Offset[{0, 10}, Scaled[{0, 1.02}]], {-1, 0}], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> padtmp + {{0, 0}, {0, 20}}]


Notice how the plot goes slightly out of the region (this was plotted on v14 for MacOS). Is there a way to disable PlotRangeClipping on top only?
I cannot use Overlay as I want the final object to be Graphics since I have more things to do as a graphic object.

I do not see the problem in V 14 on windows 10  https://i.sstatic.net/fM9HIn6t.png

Interesting! Just added an image for clarity. I am using v14 on Mac. Maybe I should run all these on Windows then.

@Nasser, actually, it does go slightly out of frame if you zoom in. This becomes apparent with a thicker line, which is what I have to plot in my use case.

The lines you have are thicker than what I have on windows 10 for some reason. I zoomed in and still do not see the curve going outside the frame. I do not have a mac to try.

@Nasser I was talking about the screenshot you mentioned. With a thin line, it maybe hard to see. Pass on PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.003] or any higher thickness, you will see. It is not a Mac issue.

I can reproducec this on win10 MMA14.

I think you can use Inset for this purpose. First, let's extract some information about the plot:
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}];
info = ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"] @ plot


{"ImagePadding" -> {{23., 6.5}, {17., 6.5}}, "ImageSize" -> {360., 227.76},
"PlotRangeSize" -> {330.5, 204.26}, "ImagePaddingSize" -> {29.5, 23.5},
"PlotRange" -> {{0., 10.}, {-1., 1.}},
"BasePlotRange" -> {{0., 10.}, {-1., 1.}}}

The aspect ratio and padding size are:
ar = 204/330.
pad = Lookup[info, "ImagePadding"]/Lookup[info, "ImageSize"]


0.618182


{{0.0638889, 0.0180556}, {0.0746399, 0.0285388}}

Then, we can use Inset:
Graphics[
    {
    Text[Row @ {"x", Superscript[10,-3]}, {0, ar/2 1.03}, {-1, -1}],
    Inset[plot, {0,0}, {0,0}, Scaled[1]]
    },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}/2 ar},
    PlotRangePadding->(pad + {{0, 0}, {0, .03}})
]


I added some padding to the top, and placed the bottom of the text at the top of the original padded plot range (before adding the extra padding).

Indirectly, you can do that manually
clip2dplot[plot_, plotRange_] := 
 Block[{}, 
  Show[plot, 
   RegionPlot[
    RegionDifference[
     Rectangle @@ (Transpose@(1. (plotRange + {{-Norm@plotRange[[1]], 
              Norm@plotRange[[1]]}, {-Norm@plotRange[[2]] , 
              Norm@plotRange[[2]] }}))), 
     Rectangle @@ (Transpose@(1. plotRange))], Frame -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None]]]   

and then as input, you need the desired plot to be clipped and specify the plot range.
clip2dplot[plot6, {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}]     


